# cat >> file in one line

Tags: bash, cat

I take notes in various textfiles and frequently do this:

```
cat >> notes.txt

better not forget this

<ctrl-D>
```

If it is only a small addition to the file, it would be good to save the extra keystrokes, pressing enter, ctrl-D

How do you do this in one line, just adding a few characters to your text file and pressing only enter afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `cat` with `echo`:

```
echo "Better not forget this" >> notes.txt
```

Comment: This is really the purest answer, but the others are definitely interesting..

Answer (score 3):

You could use a function:

```
addnotes () {
    echo "$*" >> /path/to/notes.txt
}
```

and then just add your notes as command line arguments:

```
$ addnotes better not forget this
```

Comment: Is interesting to see what power users do.. Can see if you add this to .bashrc it is always there to use

Answer (score 2):

A simple `bash` script (or function) that handles either a single line or multiple lines:

```
note() {
    # If we have text on the line use it, otherwise read from stdin
    { [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "$*" || cat; } |

    # Write current date/time, then append collected text indented by two spaces
    { date; sed 's/^/  /'; echo; } >> "$HOME/note.txt"
}
```

This allows either a simple reminder

```
note remember this
```

Or a more complex paragraph

```
note
Remember this
and this too

oh and this
<Ctrl/D>
```

The reminders are written to the file `$HOME/note.txt`, with each one prefixed by the current date/time

```
cat ~/note.txt
10 Dec 2020 16:03:59
  remember this

10 Dec 2020 16:04:05
  Remember this
  and this too

  oh and this
```

If you don't want the `date` and indentation, just remove that entire `| { ... }` segment:

```
note() { { [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "$*" || cat; } >> "$HOME/note.txt"; }
```

Or as a script (remember to make it executable and put it somewhere in your `$PATH`):

```
#!/bin/bash
{ [[ $# -gt 0 ]] && printf "%s\n" "$*" || cat; } |
    { date; sed 's/^/  /'; echo; } >> "$HOME/note.txt"
```